# return last value based on a cell value from another column in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'd like to copy the last value of sheet2 colE based on the same code number from sheet2 colA then return it on sheet0 colC. I tried using vlookup, but it does not return the last value, instead it returns the first value it finds from the column.

here is the link to the sheet for your reference.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CN3AQsGZrt18VLaHvhUTAUxBy-QG6o4ysHP5fo4MxDg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use `XLOOKUP()` with `search_mode` parameter `-1` means search last to first.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A,Sheet1!$E$2:$E,,,-1)
```

To make it dynamic spill results, use-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,Sheet1!$A$2:$A,Sheet1!$E$2:$E,,,-1))
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, will this affect the performance of the spreadsheet in the long run when there are thousands of entries?

Comment: @swayingtrees Should work faster than `VLOOKUP()`.